# Как извлечь GET параметр из URL содержащий по две квадратные скобки?

Tags: php, url, get

к сожалению не силен в PHP, долго бьюсь с задачей извлечения параметров из URL содержащих квадратные скобки. Пример строки запроса:
https://www.example.com/article/test?available%5Bfrom%5D%5Bdate%5D=18%2F12%2F2018&available%5Bto1%5D%5Bdate%5D=19%2F12%2F2018.
Как получить параметр available[from][date] и available[to1][date]? Нашел много примеров где без проблем можно получить ключи без квадратных скобок.
Н-р

```
<?php
echo filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'available',FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
?>
```

Но вот с квадратными никак не найти нужный синтаксис PHP.

Буду благодарен за любую подсказку. Конечная цель, это получить даты въезда и выезда и рассчитать разницу ночей.

Comment: `$_GET['aviable']['from']['date'], $_GET['aviable']['to']['date'] ???`

Answer (score 1):

> Как получить параметр available[from][date]

```
<?php

echo '<pre>'

. filter_var (
  $_GET ['available'] ['from'] ['date'],
  FILTER_SANITIZE_URL
);
```

Comment: Да, это работает, спасибо